# Meteor Crash: MongoError: ns name too long, max size is 128

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My Meteor app runs fine on localhost, but when I deploy it to `myApp.meteor.com`, I get the error below. I struggle to understand these error logs. Any ideas?

```
[Thu Jun 25 2015 06:35:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)] 
WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.4.18/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
throw(ex);
^
[Thu Jun 25 2015 06:35:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)] 
WARNING MongoError: ns name too long, max size is 128
at Object.Future.wait
(/meteor/dev_bundles/0.4.18/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
at [object Object].MongoConnection._ensureIndex
(packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:733:1)
at FileCollection.Mongo.Collection._ensureIndex
(packages/mongo/collection.js:620:1)
at new FileCollection (packages/vsivsi:file-
collection/gridFS_server.coffee:65:15)
at FileCollection (packages/vsivsi:file-        
collection/gridFS_server.coffee:21:24)
at app/lib/collections.js:15:12
at /meteor/containers/55bd5013-6244-5f59-9f74-
c6798eb58003/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:229:5
- - - - -
```

And the code in my `collections.js` file is listed below with line 15 noted in a comment.  It is based on the Meteor File Collection [Sample App](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-sample-app/blob/master/sample.coffee) line 10.  Note that the MD5 is actually quite a long identifier, but I'm not sure how/if it's used by Mongo.  Regardless, it works on localhost.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  console.log('collections are loading');
  myData = FileCollection('myFiles', {   // This is line 15 that triggers error
    resumable: true,                        
    http: [                                 
      {                                     
        method: 'get',
          // This GET routes path like /gridfs/myFiles/md5/9f4cd4e1d9e7cb1273ad2860fa909398.jpeg                 
        path: '/md5/:md5',                  
          // note that my :md5 also contains suffix with media type. Suffix was appended in link helper
          // I added suffix so that other programs can determine MIME type from URL's suffix, without reading file header
        lookup: function (params, query) {  
          // params.md5 contains more than the MD5 and hence needs to be split to get true MD5 portion
          var tempArray = params.md5.split('.');
          var firstHalf = tempArray[0];     // heres the MD5 part to ensure that Vaughn's code isn't affected
          return {
            md5: firstHalf                 // a query mapping url to myFiles
          };
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is related to the closed issue here: https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection/issues/55

Your local db name is probably much shorter than the one assigned to you in meteor.com environment.

Try adding something like

```
   resumableIndexName: 'fci',
```

after line

```
   resumable: true,
```

Comment: Łukasz Gozda Gandecki any idea of the problem with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177485/converting-existing-cypress-tests-to-cucumber-style-bdd-using-cypress-cucumber-p

Answer (score 1):

could you show me app/lib/collections.js:15 ?

Do you have a collection with really long name defined?

Comment: Thanks for tracing that Lukasz.  I've added the collections.js code to the OP with line 15 noted in a // comment.