# Converting existing cypress tests to cucumber style bdd using cypress-cucumber-preprocessor. Second scenario is not picked up

Tags: cucumber, cypress

We have an existing application, the tests are written in cypress. We now want to integrate a cucumber style feature which will internally run using cypress. We used `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` for the same. I followed the steps given here [on the github page](http://%60https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor%60). The problem I'm facing now, is while running tests, it shows both the scenarios, but runs only one. Shows a green tick mark next to it, but doesn't start the second one, and the clock keeps on ticking. On clicking the second scenario in the cypress launcher it says - `no commands were issued in this test.`

What have I tried:

1. I tried to duplicate the same scenario twice in the same feature file. It still runs only first one and does not move to the next one.
2. I moved both different scenarios in two different feature files. It runs both of them successfully.
3. I tried to run the example repo ([cypress-cucumber-example](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-example)) locally with n number of scenarios. That works seamlessly.

Some observations:

1. While the first test is run I ran chrome console, and saw some errors due to some network calls failing. But these calls were made (with same errors) even when I was using only cypress and hadn't integrated with cucumber, and all tests were passing. Is it because of some magic cucumber is bringing along with it? Read somewhere default cucumber waits for a test is 60 seconds, I waited for maximum 170 seconds, and then stopped the suite. At the end all I get is one scenario green and other not even started.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual features and step definitions. Having multiple scenarios in feature files obviously work, as per our test suite, the example repos, and also multiple companies using this plugin in productionAny chance for a small reproduction?

Comment: Hey @ŁukaszGozdaGandecki Thanks for responding back. It took me quite a long time, but I actually figured out what the issue was. I had an enter key after `Feature:` in my feature file. The ide didn't raise it as any problem and all was good. I was just comparing successful runs against this issue and saw that the feature name is not appearing in the UI, and hence took away the `\n`. It works like a charm now. Wondering what a small enter key can do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me quite a long time, but I actually figured out what the issue was. I had an enter key after `Feature:` in my feature file. The ide didn't raise it as any problem and all was good. I was just comparing successful runs against this issue and saw that the feature name is not appearing in the UI, and hence took away the \n. It works like a charm now. Wondering what a small enter key can do.